# Python nested JSON in GET requests

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I`m trying to connect with REST API of ServiceDesk Plus. I want to filter my query to do that i need to post nested JSON over GET method of requests library. When i try my code i get non filtered data, can you tell me why?

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://192.168.2.153:8080/api/v3/requests'
args = {
    "list_info": {
        "start_index": 1,
    "search_fields": {
        "subject": "Nadanie uprawnie"
    }
}
}
args_j = data_json = json.dumps(args)
header={"Content-Type": "application/json", "OPERATION_NAME": "GET_REQUEST",     "TECHNICIAN_KEY": "XXXXXXX-43CA-4ED3-860D-43D597720A32"}
response = requests.get(url,json=args,headers=header)
pr = response.text
print(pr)
```

Comment: You should use POST method to send json in body. However, the site seems unreachable. What error do you get exactly?

Comment: I didn`t get any error, just full response with all request without filter on "subject". In api documentation i find i should use get method for "read" a requests and it`s work in app api test envoirment(Web based). So how i should post JSON with get method ?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't send a GET request to read requests: Json data should be sent with POST method and once you do that you can retrieve all the information you need from the requests.Response object.

Comment: When i`m tryin to send POST i get Internal Error. From api docs "POST - Add / Bulk-Add entities, GET - View the information, PUT - Update the entity, details, DELETE - Delete / Bulk-delete entities"
How can i send a json with GET method in INPUT DATA? What it`s mean?
One more time from docs:
"For most of the operations, INPUT_DATA is required. It is given as a JSON string along with the parameter, while the Attributes and their values are sent along with the input data. On the other hand, the Response is exposed as JSON or XML string." maybe it`s a key?

Comment: what's the output of print(requests.get('http://192.168.2.153:8080/api/v3/requests').status_code)?

Comment: 400 but when i prepare code with auth like thisone
    import requests
    import json
    url = 'http://192.168.2.153:8080/api/v3/requests'
    args = {"OPERATION_NAME": "GET_REQUEST","TECHNICIAN_KEY": "AED48676-43CA-4ED3-860D-43D597720A32"}
    response = requests.get(url,params=args)
    print(response)
i get 200

Comment: I think the problem is in the way i trying to put JSON to api with that method. How i can add INPUT data with that json in requests lib in python?

Comment: Excuse me, you passed the json dictionary in the params keyword, it means that the data was encoded as query string in the url. If you're actually trying to send data in the params, it makes sense using the GET method, but keep in mind that you aren't sending json data.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Now i understand where is problem. I`ve checked what link is generated by test of API, now i see i need to prepare url posted to requests lib. It`s any way do it with python methods? Now i concatenate strings and it`s work, but maybe its a any better/recomended way? 
I need to get link similar to this one    "http://192.168.2.153:8080/api/v3/requests?format=json&input_data={'list_info': {'search_fields': {'subject': 'Nadanie uprawnie'}, 'start_index': 1}}"

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about what you are asking for. If you need to pass information in the **body**, use POST method, pass info in _data_ or _json_ arguments. Otherwise, if you need to send information encoded as  **query string** in the url, you can you both GET and POST methods and you have to pass data in _params_ keyword.